# Does $F(w(x))\leqslant C_wF(x)$ for a certain constant $C_w$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

*This question is fully answered, but it is strongly linked to another [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2647467/does-fwx-leqslant-c-wfx-for-a-certain-constant-c-w-with-f-being-a-di) I asked later.*

While writing a proof, I found myself needing to prove the following result.

> Let $F\colon \mathbb Q^n\to \mathbb Q$ be a function satisfying $$F(ty_1,\ldots,ty_n)=\vert t\vert F(y_1,\ldots,y_n)$$
>   for all $t$ and $(y_1,\ldots,y_n)$. If $w\in \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb Q)$, then there exists a constant $C_w$ (which does not depend on $X$), such that
>   $$F(w(X))\leqslant C_wF(X). \quad \forall X \in \mathbb{Q}^n$$

I think I should use something like $\Vert w(W)\Vert\leqslant \Vert w\Vert \cdot \Vert X\Vert$, or try to use a matrix $W=(w_{i,j})$ for $w$ and compute the coordinates of $w(x)$ in terms of $w_{i,j}$ and $x_i$.

But I can't figure it out. Any hint or solution would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is $X$ a fixed vector irrevalent of $F$ and $w$?

Comment: @AlexFrancisco Yes, absolutely. I don't want the constant to depend on $X$ though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a counterexample : define $F$ as $(x,y)\mapsto \frac{2|xy|}{|x|+|y|}$ if $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$ and $0$ otherwise, and take $w=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$. Then $F(w(0,1))=F(1,1)=2$, but $F(0,1)=0$; hence the inequality cannot hold.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Since I need this result to work, I have reinforced the condition on $F$ in order to make it work. I have done it there (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2647467/does-fwx-leqslant-c-wfx-for-a-certain-constant-c-w-with-f-being-a-di) if you want to take a look.